# .net form outputs javascript sometimes, but sometimes not

Tags: .net, internet-explorer-10

I have a .net form that has a dropdown that auto posts back.  Most of the time everything is great, I get this:

```
<td class="frmLabel">Province:</td><td><select name="ctl00$ProvinceDropDown" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$ProvinceDropDown\',\'\')', 0)" id="ctl00_ProvinceDropDown">
```

But sometimes (I'll get to the situations in a second) I get this:

```
<td class="frmLabel">Province:</td><td><select name="ctl00$ProvinceDropDown" id="ctl00_ProvinceDropDown">
```

Note the absence of the javascript that does the auto post back.

The only time the problem happens is on IE10.  Every other browser is fine.  Even IE10 in Browser Mode of IE9 or of IE10 Compatibility Mode is fine.

Obviously this feels like .Net isn't recognizing IE10 correctly.  And I'm aware of this hotfix:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600100

But:

a) I'm not getting those exact symptoms, i'm not getting '_doPostBack is undefined'.  The .net code just not generating the javascript call at all.

b) I have another sandbox host, and when I move the code there, everything is fine, even IE10.  This host doesn't have the hotfix, and has the same versions of .net (2.0 SP2, 3.0 SP2, 3.5 SP1) as the other.

Also the ie.browser file has the same content on both hosts, the regex line is still the old one, the one that's supposedly doesn't detect IE10 properly.

```
<capability name="majorversion" match="^[5-9]" />
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the hotfix at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600100 did fix the issue.  Weird.  I can't account for why my non-hotfixed host didn't experience the issue, but the last thing I'm going to dwell on is the the absence of a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` to your `<head>`. Maybe even IE=EmulateIE8 just to see if that has any effect...

Comment: I've tried every X-UA-Compatible tag I could find on the internet.  Then realized that the problem is with the very first page request, and the .net framework spitting out code, not with IE rendering html.

Answer (score 0):

edit the web.config file and in the `<system.web>` section add

```
<browserCaps>
            <case match="IE[ /](?'version'(?'major'\d+)(?'minor'\.\d+)(?'letters'\w*))">
                browser=IE
                version=${version}
                majorversion=${major}
                minorversion=${minor}
                frames=true
                tables=true
                cookies=true
                javascript=true
        javaapplets=true
                activexcontrols=true
                ecmascriptversion=1.5
                vbscript=true
                backgroundsounds=true
                isMobileDevice="true"
                <filter match="[4-9]" with="${major}">
                    ecmascriptversion=1.3
                    css1=true
                    css2=true
                    xml=true

                    <filter match="[5-9]" with="${major}">
                        w3cdomversion=1.0
                    </filter>
                  </filter>
                  <filter match="^b" with="${letters}">
                   beta=true
                </filter>                                                               
             </case></browserCaps>
```